# LinkList In C; Segmentation Fault

Tags: c, linked-list

I am creating this program in C for linkelist to take input from user just to create one node and point the head to that node and print the value and address of the node element. I am getting segmentation fault in it when I run it, please help me solve the problem.

```c
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct Node {
    int data;
    struct Node* next;
};

struct Node* head;

void main() {
    head = NULL;
    struct Node* temp = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    printf("Enter the number you want in node\n");
    scanf("%d",(int *)temp->data);
    temp->next = NULL;
    head = temp;
    printf("the address of node  is %p",head);
    printf("the value is %d",temp->data);
}
```

Comment: `scanf("%d",(int *)temp->data);` --> `scanf("%d", &temp->data);`

Comment: error: expected expression before ‘>’ token
 scanf("%d",(int *)temp->data);--> scanf("%d", &temp->data);

Comment: thanks @BLUEPIXY it came with &temp->data, :)

Answer (score 1):

```
//try this code
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
struct Node {
   int data;
  struct Node* next;
};
struct Node* head;

void main() {
   head = NULL;
  struct Node* temp = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
  printf("Enter the number you want in node\n");
  scanf("%d",&temp->data);
  temp->next = NULL;
  head = temp;
  printf("the address of node  is %p",head);
  printf("the value is %d",temp->data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, the problem is here:

```
scanf("%d",(int *)temp->data);
```

You're taking the value of `temp->data` (which is unknown because `malloc` returns uninitialized memory) and treating it as a pointer.  So `scanf` writes to some unknown memory location, causing a core dump.

You want to pass the address of this variable instead using the address-of operator `&`:

```
scanf("%d", &temp->data);
```